# My project is updated to HEAD version but when I merge Complete working copy fails

Tags: svn

I am trying to merge a branch back into my trunk. I update the trunk to the HEAD and also have updated the branch into the HEAD, I think I read somewhere that this is good practice (Is it btw?). So when I try to merge my branch into the trunk I get this Best Practices problem:
  -Complete working Copy
  Working copy should be a complete working copy (depth=infinity). If working copy is not a complete working copy, update the working copy before merging.

-First of all, What?! Don't get it...
-Second I am the only guy working on this project there are no changes on the repository to update. the project is synced to the repository. No changes. What do I update? 
Here is the error:
[image]

The history of my trunk:
[image]

The history of my branch:
[image]

If the problem is from the content of my working copy. Being that it does not have the full working copy. How do I get that depth infinity. I only have these options on checkout:

[image]

Also on the update command the only option I have are the following:

[image]

I have tried to update "Working copy" option and "fully recursive" but the problems remains. I can't make the merge.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix my problem by making an update on the plugin CollabNet MergeClient.

Answer (score 1):

Re-read definition of "Complete working copy" from this screen - it's not about revision *numbers*, but about **content of Working Copy** - you, somehow, get not the whole tree from repository, but "sparse checkout" (some subtree(s) are missing).

Just make the full `svn up`, as suggested, with `--depth 'infinity'` option, before merge